# Windows Server 2008R2 Enterprise for Web Server. Any Benefits?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, iis-7.5

Hi I've looked at the comparison charts between editions of Windows Server 2008 R2 but I don't see a definitive answer to my question.  We have licenses for Windows Server R2 Web as well as R2 Enterprise.  Our asp.net MVC3 server will run on a dedicated server with the following specs:

Dual Quad Core Xeon e5620 2.4GHz (w H/T)

- 12 gb ram
- 3Ware 9650-4LPML raid card
- 4 - 500 GB SATA drives

The server will run:

- IIS7.5
- MS SQL SERVER 2008 Enterprise
- Red5 stream server

If this service takes off, I will move the database to it's own server as well as Red5 to it's own server.

My concern is that we won't use all of the features of Enterprise and it would be more bloated than Web edition (or Standard?)

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install on Enterprise, and then, when you're ready to expand, move the Web server role (IIS 7.5) to a new server running Web Server edition

Answer (score 2):

Web edition is limited to the amount of memory that it'll support.  Also I don't think that SQL Enterprise edition will install on it.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.100%29.aspx#EEx64), the Web Edition isn't supported for SQL 2008 Enterprise x64.  However, it is supported (with some stipulations) for SQL 2008 Enterprise x32.

In that case, I would go with Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.